# Setting up properly SonarQube for Code Coverage

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, code-coverage, junit5

I'm using JUnit5 on a SpringBoot backend application server using Maven. Here is the `sonar-project.properties` file that is at the root of the project:

```
sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io
sonar.login=xxx
sonar.organization=xxx
sonar.projectKey=xxx

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.source=12

sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.test=src/test
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/test-results/TEST-**.xml
```

I use the `sonar-scanner` command line to run update the project after a build/test.

The `Overview` board on sonar-cloud looks like this:

[image: overview]

I at least got the unit tests to be recognized, but somehow I'm still at 0% in terms of code coverage. Furthermore, here is the `Measures` board:

[image: measures]

Apparently, my tests do not cover any lines whatsoever. Now, I'm aware that this means that I most probably didn't hook up the test-results properly, but I'm not sure how to do that.

What puzzles me, too, is that despite SonarQube recognizing my tests, it actually says that the lines-of-code of the tests themselves aren't tested. What is this supposed to mean?

[image: Testing tests?]

Comment: Did you run the tests after setting up Sonarqube? The code coverage is populated with the data from a run. You also need to set you the coverage variables.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Comment: This project has had Sonarqube set up for 1 week now. But I *just* started adding unit tests, hence why I did not realize that this part of it wasn't working properly. Which variable is the "coverage variable" ?

Comment: "SonarSource analyzers do not run your tests or generate reports. They only import pre-generated reports. Below you'll find language- and tool-specific analysis parameters for importing coverage and execution reports." You need to use jacoco or similar tools.

Comment: Yes, I knew about that. Using `mvn test` generates a `surefire` report: that is what I'm trying to plug in there, right? It's just hard to know which ensemble of variables should be determined.

Comment: I think it is not enough. You need to use a code coverage tool such as jacoco.

Comment: Ah! I see now. `surefire` is only for the *execution* of the tests. Somehow it produces a bunch of xml reports, but it seems like those can't be interpreted by SonarQube. I'll have to look into `jacoco`. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From SonarQube's [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/):

> SonarSource analyzers do not run your tests or generate reports. They only import pre-generated reports.

A popular library for generating code coverage for Java is [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/).

SonarQube provides [this guide](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151) to create and import Jacoco's reports.

Comment: I somehow overlooked the fact that "execution" and "coverage" are two separate things. Your answer made me realize my error. Thank you! I will mark it appropriately. Eventually, I will edit it with a working piece of `sonar-project.properties` file.

Comment: SonarQube is a beautiful tool, but they are many bits needed to make everything work.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
# SONAR CLOUD CONFIGS
sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io
sonar.organization=xxx
sonar.projectKey=xxx
sonar.login=xxx

# SOURCES
sonar.java.source=12
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# EXCLUSIONS
# (exclusion of Lombok-generated stuff comes from the `lombok.config` file)
sonar.coverage.exclusions = **/*Exception.java , **/MySpringBootApplication.java

# TESTS
sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
sonar.tests=src/test/java
```

Answer (score 3):

We have same issue. You need to add coverage blocks in your pom.xml
Can refer following sample pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.3.RELEASE
 

com.test
testapp
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
testapp
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>../target/site/jacoco-aggregate/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
      <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.5</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>coverage</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Reference URL: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-maven/maven-basic