# unit tests not being reflected in sonarqube

Tags: java, testing, sonarqube

I Have an application where I have multiple custom exceptions. Even after writing unit test cases , the code coverage for those custom Exceptions still shows zero. can anyone help me know where I am going wrong.

cutom exception

```
public class ActiveScheduleModificationException extends MDSFeedException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7993708306216285626L;

    public ActiveScheduleModificationException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

unit test case

```
@Test(expected = ActiveScheduleModificationException.class)
    public void ActiveScheduleModificationExceptionTest() {
        throw new ActiveScheduleModificationException("ActiveScheduleModificationException testing");
    }
```

Comment: we are gonna need more information. Does the other unit test works? Does Jacoco cover html report show anything odd?

Comment: Yes @BabyishTank without a Jacoco coverage report there is no possibility for SonarQube to know the Test Coverage.

Comment: Maybe this can help you @tarun nt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011373/setting-up-properly-sonarqubes-for-code-coverage this has some info as well as the official documentation here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/